# Book with people who wake up in pods in the middle of the street

Tags: story-identification, books

I don't remember much about this story other than it is quite old. In the plot all I can remember is that there were a group of people who wake up in pods in the middle of the street of a town. I think they were buildings like a grocery store that were similar to what you would find on earth. I don't remember much in between information but towards the end they meet these alien beings or higher powers. That's about all I can remember.

Comment: Any other thing? How characters looked like.. Plots..

Comment: Were they all old/late-middle aged? Did they like swimming?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised the film Cocoon [was based on a book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2224600.Cocoon). However I've had a quick scan through the book and it doesn't match the description.

Comment: They were like middle aged maybe. I think the book started with some guy in the London airport. These people were like in different places b4 they waked up in the "alien place"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That sounds like Edmund Cooper's *[Sea-Horse in the Sky](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9022)* (1969).

As [summarized at goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1113525.Sea_Horse_in_the_Sky):

> This little-known story begins when **over a dozen people awake in
> coffins**. They find themselves in an **area made to look like a town**--it
> contains a **stocked store**, a hotel, [an] inoperable car and plastic coffins,
> each containing a passenger from an international flight, each
> apparently snatched out of midair, since there's no flight wreckage and
> all seem alive and unharmed. The people slowly gather in the hotel and
> find themselves able to understand one another, even [though] they don't
> all speak the same language. None of them has an idea what they're
> doing in this new place and there isn't anything for miles around their
> little settlement except a seemingly endless expanse of grass. After
> weeks of waiting for rescue that never arrives, a few of them explore
> and discover this mysterious land is also populated by a group of what
> appear to be medieval people and a group of what seems to be cavemen.
> That accounts for the human population on the island. The only other
> creatures around are **sinister metal spiders**.

Comment: YES THIS IS IT. THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome!